# Storyboard - let view scale itself but within constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

I'm completely stuck with getting along storyboards.

What I'm trying to do is the view that basically groups two label to look like this:
[image]

So I want the quote and the author right under the quote which is anchored to right edge.

This view will be reused multiple times so I created a xib for that which looks like this.[image]
As you can see the view is free form and the quote label centered with the author label anchored to the right edge of it.

What I expect from it that I can place it in the storyboard view controller with the following conditions:

- This view has as much width as it needs but it shrinks if too width to make at least 10 points from each side
- This view has as much height as it needs but aligns at center of the parent view horizontally.

So I've added it to the view and set the following constaints.

[image]

But when I compile I see the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see that you included images from a custom "Size class", not Any x Any. You are not mixing things up right? And know about the basics of Size Classes?

Comment: Select ViewController in storyboard -> InfoPanel -> Identity and Type -> Size classes checkmark.

I would strongly recommend to use the Size Classes feature. It helps you refine Autolayout constraints (that you have added in Any x Any) for different screen sizes. Eto harasho i udobno :)